# in Jquery mobile - change size of icon button in header

Tags: jquery-mobile

im trying to add info "i" button in the header left size.

i did it but the button appear very small and not in the center of the header height.
this is the code of the header:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    <div>           
        <h2 style="text-align: center">something written here</h2>
    </div>      
</div><!-- /header -->
```

i want to enlarge the info "i" button, and also put it in the left and in the center of the height of the header line. how can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need that div around h2?.If you remove that div header height will be reduced a bit.

Comment: all the icons are on one sprite sheet you would have to modify the css or the image on the sprite sheet to increase the icon size :)

Comment: i have put the h2 cause, before i added him the text i wanted to show in the header was uncomplete: insted of "something written here" i saw in the device "something wri...."

Comment: h2 is fine.What about the div around h2?

Answer (score 1):

Following is correct syntax

Remove div around h2, it will mess the jquery css.

Try Changing h2 to h1. So the button will come in center of the hearer height.

Try giving the button class... class="ui-btn-left"

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="delete" class="ui-btn-left" >Button Left</a>
    <h1>Edit Contact</h1>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="check" class="ui-btn-right" >Button Right</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Right out the of docs.. great answer! I dealt with this as well, and found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html that the correct way to ensure proper positioning of header icons, is to use the classes: ui-btn-left and ui-btn-right

Answer (score 0):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/21/ (Width)
- http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/35/ (Height)

JS:

```
// For all buttons use something like this
$('.ui-btn').css('width','50%');

// For individual buttons use something like this
$('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

// Or this for HREF data-role buttons
$('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');
```

UPDATE: (I think this is what you're looking for)

```
// this changes the height for all buttons
$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px');

// This changes the height for a single element 
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','30px');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton1" value="Press Me 1" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton2" value="Press Me 2" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton3" value="Press Me 3" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton4" value="Press Me 4" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton1">HREF Me 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton2">HREF Me 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton3">HREF Me 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton4">HREF Me 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```